# CloudFront CDN (No GZip) vs Webserver / Local For all CSS / JS

Tags: wordpress, optimization, cdn, amazon-cloudfront, pagespeed

I am currently in the process of running some optimizations for WordPress site we are soon deploying.  We are using w3 Total Cache for optimizations on the site.  I have recently signed up for CloudFront for a CDN and I feel this has definitely helped but we are losing gzip compression for css/js files using this.

I wanted to see if anyone had any opinions on a good way to handle this.  Currently I am hosting all js/css from the webserver and it seems to give better performance (using PageSpeed Insights add on for Google Chrome)

This is more of a best practice question to help me get some insight on this scenario.

Anyone have any recommendations?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After spending some time testing I have found the best way for our workflow is to have the css / js assets gzip on the server rather than serving from cloudfront.

It just seems way faster to serve the gzipped files on the server side than to serve non-gzipped files from cloudfront.

I feel the suggestion that @Ryan Parman makes perfect sense if we were not editing the css/js very often.  I suppose there are some ways to create a script to sync the css/js after editing but for the current project what I have suggested above works like a charm and is fast!

Answer (score 1):

You can pre-gzip the JavaScript and CSS files, upload them to S3 with an `application/x-gzip` HTTP header, then have CloudFront serve them out.

If you automate the process as part of your build/deployment workflow, it's pretty easy to maintain.

Comment: Thanks Ryan.  I feel like this answer is in the right direction but unfortunately would be a bit too much to add to our workflow. +1